# How does a program determine the end of a string?

Tags: string, assembly, masm, c-strings, null-terminated

I can define a new variable like so `msg db 'Hello, world!$'`, or another way `msg2 db 'Hello, world!', 0`
I know that the end of a string is determined using value `0` in memory. What is symbol `$` standing for then?

Comment: MS-DOS convention (for many DOS function calls) was to terminate strings with a $ instead of 0. If you aren't calling MS-DOS then you don't want the $. Whether a string had to be $ terminated or not was dependent on the DOS function being called.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I saw `$` at the end of a string in a relatively modern book. I would appreciate if you can reason your words with historical remarks. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Michael Petch: Interrupt 21h service 09h is actually the only "CP/M-style" function which takes a dollar-terminated string. All other DOS functions use ASCIZ or pointer + length to determine length.

Comment: I can't make any comment about a modern book unless I know which book. Which book are you reading? Or what webpage was it (if it was a webpage)? I have access to a lot of books so I may have the one you are looking at.

Comment: For example historical info about DOS shows that Int 21h/Ah=9 (which you can read about here: http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2562.htm) uses a $ terminated string. If that modern book is showing how to print something to standard output in DOS then the example code they are using would require a $ for that function.

Comment: For the reasons the interrupt 21h function 09h DOS service used the dollar sign, refer to https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/7638/why-did-dos-use-dollar-terminated-strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does a program determine the end of a string?

It depends on the program. A good program would do something like (NASM syntax):

```
string:    db "Hello World!"
.end:

    mov ecx,string.end - string   ; ecx = length of the string
```

..and would keep track of string length/s during any modifications (append, truncate, concatenate, etc) so that it always knows the length of strings with almost no overhead at all.

A "less good" program might put the string's length at the beginning of the string. This is something that was done by some old programming languages (e.g. Pascal). This causes problems when you want to work with overlapping strings (e.g. if `string2` is the last half of `string1` then you can't save memory by making the strings overlap in memory because you'd have to insert a length at the start of `string2` that would corrupt the middle of `string1`).

A "less good" program might also waste CPU time searching the string looking for some kind of terminator (where how bad it is depends on how long the string is - extremely bad for extremely long strings). For MS-DOS that terminator is a `'$'` character (which makes it extra silly/annoying if you want to have a `'$'` character in the middle of the string), and for most other cases (e.g. C programming) it's a zero (null character).

Of course for assembly language you can mostly do whatever you like (and can write a good program); until you have to use code that someone else wrote (e.g. MS-DOS API, or code written in some other language).

Comment: You can write with the DOS interrupt 21h function 40h, bx = 1 (stdout handle), ds:dx -> data, cx = length instead. This is exactly the same data sink as function 09h, just a different interface.

Comment: Since this question was tagged [masm] it can be simplified in the example to `mov ecx, sizeof msg`